# Torch - Large input and output sizes into neural network

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, prediction, torch

I'm new to machine learning and seek some help.
I would like to train a network to predict the next values I expect as follow:

reference: [val1 val2 ... val 15]

val = 0 if it doesn't exists, 1 if it does exist.

Input: [1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 0]

Output: [1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 1 1] (last two values appear)

So my neural network would have 15 inputs and 15 outputs

I would like to know if there would be a better way to do that kind of prediction. Do my data would need normalization also?

Now the problem is, I dont have 15 values, but actually 600'000 of them. Can a neural network handle such big tensors, and I've hear I would need twice the number for hidden layer units.

Thanks a lot for your help, you machine learning expert!

Best

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not a problem for the concept of a neural network: the question is whether your computing configuration and framework implementation deliver the required memory.  Since you haven't described your topology, there's not a lot we can do to help you scope this out.  What do you have for parameter and weight counts?  Each of those is at least a short float (4 bytes).  For instance, a direct FC (fully-connected) layer would give you (6e5)^2 weights, or 3.6e11 * 4 bytes => 1.44e12 bytes.  Yes, that's pushing 1.5 terabytes for that layer's weights.

You can get around some of this with the style of NN you choose.  For instance, splitting into separate channels (say, 60 channels of 1000 features each) can give you significant memory savings, albeit at the cost of speed in training (more layers) and perhaps some accuracy (although crossover can fix a lot of that).  Convolutions can also save you overall memory, again at the cost of training speed.

---

600K => 4 => 600K

That clarification takes care of my main worries: you have 600,000 * 4 weights in each of two places: 1,200,004 parameters and 4.8M weights. That's 6M total floats, which shouldn't stress the RAM of any modern general-purpose computer.

The channelling idea is when you're trying to have a fatter connection between layers, such as 600K => 600K FC.  In that case, you break up the data into smaller groups (usually just 2-12), and make a bunch of parallel fully-connected stream.  For instance, you could take your input and make 10 streams, each of which is 60K => 60K FC.  In your next layer, you swap the organization, "dealing out" each set of 60K so that 1/10 goes into each of the next channels.

This way, you have only 10 * 60K * 60K weights, only 10% as many as before ... but now there are 3 layers.  Still, it's a 5x saving on memory required for weights, which is where you have the combinatorial explosion.

Comment: Hello Prune, thanks a lot for taking the time to answer! I'm not yet at that stage in terms of machine learning language ;) So far I use torch and my NN is the following: Sequential Container: Linear(600K, 4HU) -> ReLu->Linear(4, 600K)-> SoftMax. With a learning rate of 0.01 and the number of iteration (passes over the dataset) is 100.  Also it is a FC network (Sequential). I thought CNN were more adapted to image processing and not 1D sequential data...By using 600 channels and 1000 features, how should my data be organized so? Thanks again

Comment: What is "4HU"?  This looks like you have a hidden layer of only 4 neurons?

Comment: Yes 4 neurons, Hidden Units I meant, sorry. I'm now trying to use SparseLinea

Comment: Thanks for the update (didn't get a notification for that sorry). I'm not exactly confortable with your explanation (my bad as I'm new to neural networks and modelization of features). So basically you propose to use parallel FC network instead? Is it different from your first proposition?

Comment: If the current topology gives you appropriate output, stick with it.  I'm worried that only 4 HUs can properly predict additions to a set of 600k inputs,  If it does work, stick with it; that would be a great, efficient topology.  My suggestions have two basic points: (1) You do *not* want to use FC layers at this magnitude; (2) If your present topology doesn't work, there are ways to work around the magnitude.

Comment: Thanks! I'm using Torch, and for now the following topology:
nn.Sequential {
  [input -> (1) -> (2) -> (3) -> output]
  (1): nn.SparseLinear
  (2): nn.ReLU
  (3): nn.Linear(1000 -> 759778)
}
I train on 20 samples. Input and output are 2D matrices with pairs {index, 1} of size 200 and 10 respectively, index taken over 760K. The thing is I don't know which criterion to use and with already that setup it takes quite some time to process indeed... Not sure if Torch provide not FC modules, and if not, how can I split my data is a mystery to me for now :-/

Comment: There's nothing that says you have to use a FC layer at the end; the result can be a vector instead of a classification.  I hit a question on SO yesterday that showed how to do this, but I can't find it for you now.  Splitting the input comes with the term "Siamese"; there are plenty of examples.  However, I'm hopeful that you won't have to go that far.  As for speed, what are you using for hardware (which CPU/GPU, how much memory)?

Comment: Ahah, just my Macbook ;) I'm doing a semester project at school so not really in the structure of Industry... But thanks for your ideas, it's been a good start. I'm not looking into RNN as my data is temporal.